# keep same order in flot stack chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I've this problem which I can't fix. I want to create a Flot stack chart. The graph is created by the colour order is not respected as shown in this figure:

[image]

If you can note that in `2010-2011` and `2011-2012` the blue must be first.
Here the code used to get this:

> ```
>       dataset = [
>             {label: "Staff", data: staffRep, color: "#0077FF"},
>             {label: "Post-doc", data: postdocRep, color: "#7D0096"},
>             {label: "Student", data: studentRep, color: "#DE000F"}
>         ];
> ```

```
        var bar_options = {
            series: {
                stack: true,
                bars: {
                    barWidth: 0.2,
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    show: true
                }
            },
            bars: {
                align: "center"
            },
            xaxis: {
                tickLength: 0,
                ticks: ticks,
                axisLabel: 'Reporting period',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 13,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 15
            },
            yaxis: {
                //max: max + j - j/2, // to avoid interference between bars and legend
                axisLabel: 'Personnel',
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 13,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                axisLabelPadding: 5
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            legend: {
                backgroundColor: "#EEE",
                labelBoxBorderColor: "none"
            },
            colors:["#004078","#207800", "#613C00"]
        };
        $.plot($("#barchart"), dataset, bar_options);
```

Comment: Can you post up the data variables (staffRep, postdocRep, studentRep)?

Comment: You need so show us your data, in particular what do `staffRep`, `postdocRep`, and `studentRep` equal?  I started to try and recreate your problem here (http://jsfiddle.net/W9QXe/) but can not.

Comment: The problem is in these arrays, `postdocRep` and `studentRep` have undefined values (I work with values from database), I changed the undefined by 0 and it's working now. Thanks